# Python: Sending an argument with a command in Discord

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I am currently working on a Discord bot using Python, but I seemed to have gotten stuck with my code. When I sent me the '.fate' command I realized, I didn't give an argument, and the bot already sent me a response.

This is my code:

```
import random

class Questions(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
  
  @commands.command()
  async def fate(self, ctx, arg):
    answer = ['Yes.', 'No.', 'Maybe.','In the near future.', 'Ask again later.','Reply hazy try again.', 'Most likely.', 'Better not tell you now.', 'Concentrate and ask again.', 'Cannot predict now.', 'Very doubtful.']
    value = random.choice(answer)
    await ctx.send(f'{arg} {value}')
    else:
       await ctx.send('You need to give an argument, wise one.')

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Questions(client))
```

I am not really sure what I need to add to the code to make the argument work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to make is an 8ball command.

**An easy way** to accomplish this would be to set the default value of the arg parameter to None, then checking if it is None to figure out whether the user has given an argument or not. Also note that I changed it to `*, arg` which you can read about [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments). This is because arguments are separated by spaces and so if the question the user asks spans multiple words, it will only show the first word otherwise, with this addition it will show the whole question.

```
@commands.command()
async def fate(self, ctx, *, arg=None):
    if arg is None:
        await ctx.send('You need to give an argument, wise one.')
        return
    answer = ['Yes.', 'No.', 'Maybe.','In the near future.', 'Ask again later.','Reply hazy try again.', 'Most likely.', 'Better not tell you now.', 'Concentrate and ask again.', 'Cannot predict now.', 'Very doubtful.']
    value = random.choice(answer)
    await ctx.send(f'{arg} {value}')
```

**The more nicer way** to do this is by error handling the command which you can read more on [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands#error-handling). This has more flexibility because you can handle multiple errors and not clog up the main command block with the error handling code.

```
@fate.error
async def fate_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("You need to give an argument, wise one.")
```

You should consider reading up on the [official documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) if you want a better idea on how the commands system works.